# How to set the window size for video swin transformer?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, pytorch-lightning

I am confused with the window size setting for the video Swin transformer. I have a data input with the shape `(200, 8, 8)`, the height and width are 8, and the number of `single channel` frames is 200. I need each patch to have a dimension of `1x1x10`.

I refer to [this code](https://github.com/haofanwang/video-swin-transformer-pytorch/tree/main), and I created a dummy data `dummy_x = torch.rand(1, 1, 200, 8, 8)`. The swin transformer that I set is the following tiny swin blocks.

```
model = SwinTransformer3D(pretrained=None,
                 pretrained2d=True,
                 patch_size=(10,1,1),
                 in_chans=1,
                 embed_dim=96,
                 depths=[2, 2, 6, 2],
                 num_heads=[3, 6, 12, 24],
                 window_size=(20,7,7),
                 mlp_ratio=4.,
                 qkv_bias=True,
                 qk_scale=None,
                 drop_rate=0.,
                 attn_drop_rate=0.,
                 drop_path_rate=0.2,
                 norm_layer=torch.nn.LayerNorm,
                 patch_norm=True,
                 frozen_stages=-1,
                 use_checkpoint=False)
```

How to set the window size for the depth (frames)?

For example, window size is set to `(7,7)` in 2D swin swin. What the number 7 is indicating here? And how to set the window size for the 3D Swin transformer.
In my settings, I set it as `(20,7,7)`. Is this correct? how it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified a window size of `(20, 7, 7)`, which means each patch will attend to a 20-frame depth and a `7x7` spatial region in the height and width dimensions of your input data, matching your desired patch dimension of `1x1x10`. So u can use below code :

```
input_shape = (200, 8, 8)

patch_size = (1, 1, 10)

window_size = (input_shape[0] // patch_size[0], input_shape[1] // patch_size[1], input_shape[2] // patch_size[2])

 model = SwinTransformer3D(
    patch_size=patch_size,
    in_chans=1,  
    embed_dim=96, 
    depths=[2, 2, 6, 2],  
    num_heads=[3, 6, 12, 24], 
    window_size=window_size,  
    mlp_ratio=4.0, 
    qkv_bias=True,  
    qk_scale=None, 
    drop_rate=0.0, 
    attn_drop_rate=0.0, 
    drop_path_rate=0.2,  
    patch_norm=False, 
    frozen_stages=-1, 
    use_checkpoint=False 
)

print(model)
```

Comment: `patch_size` order should not be `(10,1,1)` cosidering depth first?